# date from string

Tags: iphone, date

I have string like @"2011-03-29 15:22:16"
and I use dateformatter to get NSdate obj.
Below is my code:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2011-03-29 15:22:16";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

However, date is always NULL.

I tried several time&date style, and failed either.

So can this kind of string be formatted into the NSDate object?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the format is incorrect. Try setting it manually.

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2011-03-29 15:22:16";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Comment: @scorpiozj - You are welcome and it's not a stupid question. It's en easy question for someone with more than 10 years of experience, but sometimes a hard one for someone with less

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try following.

```
mDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

// 2010-11-11 17:26:59
[mDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```